# Is it possible to change a question's reason for closure?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538424/suppose-a-and-b-are-two-relatively-prime-numbers-then-what-are-the-possible-val) question about $\gcd(a+b, a^2+b^2)$ picked up several closure votes in an early state where it was somewhat unclear about what it was asking (though it obviously wasn't too hard to puzzle out).  It subsequently got revised to make things much clearer - but in the process it became clear that the Q was a duplicate.  I put up the fifth vote to close because of the duplicate-ness, but the closure reason is listed as 'unclear what you're asking' because of the initial confusing question, even though IMHO the current form of the question isn't unclear at all but *is* a clear duplicate.

My question is, is it possible and/or would it make sense to change the closure reason, either by reopening the Q or in some more adminnish fashion?  It's obviously a small thing, and I'm not terribly sussed if it doesn't happen, but this seems like a somewhat unusual case...

Comment: Looking at the question, I think it makes more sense to just merge it into the one you pointed out it was a duplicate of.  I'll do this presently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moderators can (as in, it is supported by the software) re-open and re-close the question to change the closure vote reason. For future reference, it usually suffices that you flag the question and give us a good reason why you think the closure reason should change.